# Unable to get access token from FuelAuth Node Module

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, oauth2, node.js

I'm playing around with the [FuelAuth module](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Node-Auth) in Node. I want to use it to [return an access token](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Node-Auth/wiki/getAccessToken) which I can use to interact with other objects via API (objects not available in the Node SDK)

My issue is that my code returns this generic error

```
{ message: 'Unauthorized', errorcode: 1, documentation: '' }
```

This is the code that i'm using...I've triple checked my client Id and Client secret are correct. Also authOrigin = auth endpoint

```
const sfmcAuth = new FuelAuth({
    clientId: clientId
    , clientSecret: clientSecret
    , authOrigin: authOrigin
})

sfmcAuth.getAccessToken()
    .then( (data) => {
        console.log(data)
    });
```

Comment: Follow examples in https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Node-REST . It uses FuelAuth and has more complete examples.

Comment: I've followed that example, but i get "Error: No access token"

Answer (score 1):

Okay so i figured it out! My problem was twofold;

1. I didn't need to use the Fuel-Auth module seperately to access the Fuel-Rest module. The fuel rest takes care of the authentication
2. The parameters i passed into the options object when creating a new FuelRest class were slightly incorrect (had to dig in the Fuel-auth git code to figure this one out). Basically, I needed to define my authUrl as the auth endpoint + 'v2/token'. Also, I needed to pass an object called authOptions with a parameter called authVersion = 2. See below for the final code that worked

```
const options = {
    auth: {
        // options you want passed when Fuel Auth is initialized
        clientId: clientId,
        clientSecret: clientSecret,
        authUrl: authOrigin + 'v2/token',
        authOptions: {
            authVersion: 2
        }
    },
    origin: origin 
};

const sfmcRest = new FuelRest(options) 

sfmcRest.get({
    uri: `/platform/v1/endpoints`
})
    .then( response => {
        console.log(response.body.items)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

As per sfmc-fuelsdk-node version 2.4, you can use the below syntax for initializing the client.

Note :- If authOrigin is defined then the library will not consider the stack value. you can pass null for it.

```
const client = new ET_Client(clientId, clientSecret, stack, {origin, authOrigin, soapOrigin, authOptions: { 
    authVersion: 2
  }});
```